# Can I use Request or other facade in eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Forgive me my poor English.I am a newbie for laravel.I have a few questions about the laravel eloquent model.I dont know if it is reasonable to use Requset object or other Facades in model class? Are these facades only for controller use?
Thank you

Comment: Model (logic, data) View(presentation of logic and data) Controllers Bridge for requests towards model <-> views. So you want some of controller responsibillity to move it to the model ? Not a good way to go.

Comment: Sometimes I simply want the the codes in the controller to seem a little bit slim, so I want  to move some logic to the model

Comment: correct, then just pass the request instance to a function and refactor based on singe responsibillity!

Answer (score 0):

No, facades can be use any where. For instance, you can use the Request facade anywhere even in views.